# Animation wheel effect in android

Tags: android, animation

Is there any way to create a ray animation behind buttons in Android like this https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-spin

It should just rotate behind the coin.

[image: like this pic]

That rays should rotate within the rectangle of the parent layout.
Any easy way to do it?

My code:

```
final Animation animRotate = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context,R.anim.image_rotate);

 ImageView rl2=(ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.ss);

rl2.startAnimation(animRotate);

and xml file:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator">
    <rotate
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:fromDegrees="0"
        android:toDegrees="360"
        android:duration="10000"
        android:repeatMode="restart"
        android:repeatCount="-1"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%">
    </rotate>
</set>
```

Comment: Are you able to rotate it?

Comment: yes i m able to rotate the image.but my problem is, when it is rotating it its view is out of this layout. my problem is the cut off of the rotation image, in example: I have a imageview in a relativelayout view and want to rotate it so that it is centered and cut off the border of the parent layout.

Comment: On both the ImageView and it's parent in your XML file, try setting android:clipChildren="false" and android:clipToPadding="false"

Comment: Thanks for replying.but it has shown as like before.nothing changed after giving these attribute.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **objectAnimator** to achieve this.

```
<objectAnimator
android:duration="3000"
    android:propertyName="rotation"
    android:repeatCount="infinite"
    android:repeatMode="reverse"
    android:valueTo="360"
    android:valueType="floatType" />
```

And one more thing **accelerate_decelerate_interpolator** makes the animation speed up at the start and slow down at the end.

Comment: Thanks for replying. when it is rotating it its view is out of this layout. my problem is the cut off of the rotation image, in example: I have a imageview in a relativelayout view and want to rotate it so that it is centered and cut off the border of the parent layout.

Comment: i have added a link above.can we achive like this in another way.without using imageview in relativelayout.i mean without rotating image.

Comment: i have put it above.please check it out.

Comment: Apply the animation in the background(i.e. ray image) and check it once. And please post your layout contents having those imageviews.

Comment: <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rl"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        
           >
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ss"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/bg"
                />
<Relativelayout>

Comment: can we achive this in another way?

Comment: I think, anyhow you have to use animator to achieve it.

Answer (score 1):

Rotate your background image with respect to pivot point, pivot point will be center point of image.

```
ImageView img = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.ss);


        RotateAnimation rotateAnimation = new RotateAnimation(0f,360f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,0.5f);
        rotateAnimation.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
        rotateAnimation.setDuration(1000);
        rotateAnimation.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
        img.startAnimation(rotateAnimation);
```